# Erro em uso de Action assíncrona (Async)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, async

Esta action deve enviar um e-mail de forma Assíncrona, tudo muito simples até então, inclusive uso a mesma classe em outros projetos com a mesma versão do MVC. Porém para a minha surpresa, neste projeto não roda. Simplesmente aparece o erro abaixo.

Error:

> The asynchronous action method 'EsqueciMinhaSenha' returns a
>   Task, which cannot be executed synchronously.

Stacktrace:

> at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__12()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.b__14()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext

Action:

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> EsqueciMinhaSenha(UsuarioEsqueciMinhaSenhaViewModel vModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var conteudo = "este é o conteudo do email";
            var nomeDestinatario = "esse é o nome do destinatário";

            if(await EmailService.SendAsync(Language.PasswordRecovery, conteudo, vModel.EmailOuUsername, nomeDestinatario))
            {
                TempData["MensagemRetorno"] = Language.EmailSendedWithSuccess;
                return View("login");
            }
        }

        TempData["MensagemRetorno"] = Language.ErrorSendingEmail;
        return View("EsqueciMinhaSenha");
    }
```

Envio do e-mail:

```
public static async Task<bool> SendAsync(string assunto, string conteudo, string destinatario, string nomeDestinatario)
{
    // Habilitar o envio de e-mail
    var appSetting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

    if (appSetting != null && appSetting.Count >= 7 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(assunto) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(conteudo) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(destinatario) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(nomeDestinatario))
    {
        int port = 0;
        bool useSSl = false;

        using (var msg = new MailMessage
        {
            From = new MailAddress(appSetting["EmailFrom"], appSetting["EmailNameFrom"]),
            Body = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(conteudo)
        })
        {
            int.TryParse(appSetting["EmailPort"], out port);
            bool.TryParse(appSetting["EmailUseSSL"], out useSSl);


            msg.ReplyToList.Add(destinatario);
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(destinatario, nomeDestinatario));
            msg.Subject = assunto;
            msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(msg.Body, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain));
            msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(msg.Body, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html));

            using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(appSetting["EmailServer"], port))
            {
                var credentials = new NetworkCredential(appSetting["EmailUserName"], appSetting["EmailPassword"]);
                smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = useSSl;
                await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(msg);

                return await Task.FromResult(true);
            }
        }
    }

    return await Task.FromResult(false);
}
```

Comment: Qual a versão do .NET Framework?

Comment: @jbueno os projetos da solution estão todos setados para 4.5

Comment: E você tem a 4.6 disponível? Tente trocar o projeto que tá com erro pra 4.6 e testar, eu vi em algum lugar que existia um bug que causava exatamente isso na 4.5 beta. Então pode ser isso.

Comment: @jbueno irei tentar, mas acredito que não vai mudar nada, se não me engano eu já fiz o inverso, acho que era 4.6 e troquei para 4.5... mas na verdade eu citei ali que tenho um outro projeto nas mesmas versões e tudo funciona perfeitamente... o mesmo código e etc.

Comment: o erro é local ou no servidor?

Comment: @sir_ask é local, ainda não subi nenhuma versão

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994335/the-asynchronous-action-method-returns-a-task-which-cannot-be-executed-synchron

Comment: confirma que todas as dll's q tens estao ok,

Comment: @sir_ask esta tudo ok! Inclusive antes de postar aqui já olhei milhares de postagens a respeito e nada resolve.